# how to mask an image using numpy only

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

Why this mask layer does not mask image.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy
path = 'inp.jpg'
arr = numpy.array(Image.open(path))
 img = mpimg.imread(path)
 black_pixels_mask = np.all(img == [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)
 img[black_pixels_mask] = [255,255,255]
```

The result img should be the masked one.and the code should replace black to white. Just as a sample colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
arr[numpy.all(arr == [0, 0, 0], axis=-1)]=[255,255,255]
data = Image.fromarray(arr)
data.save(path)
```